# While using 7zip in batch it always creates a folder with the same name as the of the folder i extracted it from

Tags: batch-file

Whenever i run this it creates a folder in the directory i extract it to with the name of the folder i archived it from.

```
 @echo off
set /P path=Archive frome where? 
set /P path2=Where to extract? 
cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip
7zg a %path%.zip %path%
mkdir %path2%
7zg e %path%.zip -o%path2% -y
```

Comment: Asise from your question, (which is essentially, "so that I do not have to read or learn the command line options for my specific piece of software, can you tell me how it works?"), other than your first line, _(which I assume shouldn't be preceded with an unnecessary space character)_, every other line requires improvement.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
@echo off
set /P "pathOfFileUncompressed=Archive from where?>" 
set /P "pathOfFileCompressed=Where to extract?>"
set /P "nameOfZipFile=What will the compressed file be called?>"
cd /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
7zg.exe a "%pathOfFileCompressed%\%nameOfZipFile%.zip" "%pathOfFileUncompressed%"
```